# Error executing: CREATE DATABASE aNewDb . Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: sql, postgresql

Main class where the code is running :

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "postgres";
static final String PASS = "postgres";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        // STEP 1: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        //STEP 2: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //STEP 3: Execute a query
        ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn);
        //Creating a reader object

        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\PROJECTS\\SQL\\src\\main\\resources\\createDatabaseAndUser.sql"));

        //Running the script
        sr.runScript(reader);
```

And this is the file createDatabaseAndUser.sql :

```
CREATE DATABASE aNewDb;
```

I am trying to run my program in IDEA and I receive the ERROR :

```
Connecting to database...
CREATE DATABASE aNewDb
Error executing: CREATE DATABASE aNewDb.
Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

When I run this script without program ( without Main.class ) everything is OK and the database created without any problems.

Comment: CREATE DATABASE query can not be run into a transaction block
 conn.setAutoCommit(true); could be a workaround but not sure if it's secure
and specially if you want that your sql statements are executed as a unit

Comment: @user2222 How can I fix it?
conn.setAutoCommit(false) ?

Comment: autocommit is false by default, 
try to set it to true conn.setAutoCommit(true);

Comment: @user2222 I tried to set it after this line : 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
but It didn't help..

Comment: @user2222 I have a task and I should create database in SQL script and further use it

Comment: from wich package do you import ScriptRunner?

Comment: @user2222 import org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner;

Comment: in step 3
ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn);
sr.setAutoCommit(true);

Comment: @user2222 It helped! Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!